# Passing Pointers By Reference vs Passing Pointers Into Functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, prototype

It's been a while since I've coded anything in C++. While I was trying to help another person as a CIS Tutor, he wanted to know why it's necessary to have an ampersand next to a pointer to an int.

I figured that if you were to pass a pointer by reference and you point to something else, the main knows after you passed that val will equal to whatever you set it equal to.

There will be an example below will demonstrate what I'm trying to say.

Is this correct?

```
//main function
int variable = 0;
int* val = &variable;
function1(val);
cout << *val << endl;
function2(val);
cout << *val << endl;
```

```
//Passing in a pointer with reference.
void function1(int*& value)
{
    int variable = 9;
    value = &variable;
}
```

```
//Passing in a pointer without reference.
void function2(int* val)
{
    int variable = 9;
    value = &variable;
}
```

My assumption is that the program will output 9 instead of 8 or 0. I hope this give you guys a clear picture of what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: *A pointer to an int in the prototype

Comment: Are you asking why a function would have a signature like `void function1(int*& value)`?

Comment: your `function1` is broken. The caller will be left with `val` being a dangling pointer

Comment: function 2 is broken - nothing called 'value',  the parameter is 'val'.  It is always good to compile a [MCVE] before you submit it.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between passing the values and passing the reference is the same with pointers as with other values (actually pointers are nothing special they just hold numbers that sometimes are adresses of other objects).

With `int`:

```
void foo(int x) { x = 1; }
void bar(int& x) { x = 2; }

int main() {
    int y = 5;
    foo(y);
    std::cout << y; // prints 5
    bar(y); 
    std::cout << y; // prints 2
}
```

Now with pointers:

```
void foo(int* x) { x = 0; }
void bar(int*& x) { x = 0; }

int main() {
     int y = 42;
     int* z = &y;
     foo(z);     
     std::cout << z; // prints the address of y
     bar(z); 
     std::cout << z; // prints 0
}
```

Note that your `function1` is broken, because when you call it

```
int* y;
function1(y);
std::cout << *y;    // **baaam**
                    // the value y points to is already gone
```

the `int` inside the function ends its lifetime when the function returns and the caller cannot use the value in any meaningful way. Note that in this particular example you would probably get the "correct" value printed, but that is just by coincidence and dereferencing `y` after passing it to `function1` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The statement "cout << y << endl;" was assuming you're using the statement "using namespace std;" located at the line before main. Forgive me, I use "using namespace std;" for every one of my assignments in college.

Comment: @WilliamLee thats fine for small examples or assignments and it wont create a problem here, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for why it is considered bad practice in general. However, apart from the reasons mentioned there I simply dont see the advantage of `using namespace std;`.